# Is it possible to have IOS simulator in my Linux Mint?

Tags: unix, xcode-simulator

I need to have `iOS simulator` for my `Linux Mint OS` to check my website responsive in various iOS devices is this possible as I know this feature is available in almost all Macs but I cannot afford a Mac right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up my need by using Online simulators which perfectly resembles the actual devices output.

Here are the links for online simulators...

> http://transmog.net/
>
> https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live#ios

Answer (score 0):

The iOS simulator is a large chunk of iOS compiled for OS X (minus the app store, among other things). You won't be able to port it without the source code, which Apple isn't going to share. iOS development can be done on other platforms, but you're not going to get the simulator.

Comment: hm thankyou for the input but there may be some tricks to get that as it is not a commercial thing (I feel so).

Comment: Well, you can use OSX86 and load OS X on a regular PC. That would get you what you're looking for. I wouldn't trust this for a production environment, but it should work fine for you.